# How to make expandable list view in ionic 3 for menu

Tags: ionic3

I wants to do an expandable menu in ionic3. I have an experience in Android which has an component Expandable List View. We just create an adapter of the expandable List view and use them.

And in IOS native we used table view with section and row. While click on a particular section we just open the sub row cells of the section and rest are close.

But Ionic3 has no expandable component.
Someone please share some thought so that I can implement it ionic3.
I am sending a image of Expandable menu.
[IMAGE OF EXPANDABLE MENU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXucM.png)

Comment: you could design a page using [menu](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#menus) component and possibly angular animations for the onclick show effect

Comment: Yep . I got it. Thanks for your advice. Cheers